# Выдает оишбку list index out of range

Tags: python

мне нужно заменить значения моего двумерного массива исходя из условия , но когда я пытаюсь установить значение нужного мне элемента то выдает оишбку , оишбка вознимкает во всех строчках где первый индекс моего массива является i, массив я загружаю из другого файла

```
import c01
def gen_var_table_3():
   i=0
   i0=0
   i1=0
   i2=0
   sum100=0
   flag_good=0
   for a in range(i0,c01.CNT_Xsize,1):
       for b in range(i1,c01.CNT_Xsize,1):
           for c in range(i2,c01.CNT_Xsize,1):
              flag_good=0
              if(a!=b):
                 flag_good+=1
              if(a!=c):
                 flag_good+=1
              if(b!=c):
                 flag_good+=1
              if(flag_good==3):
                 c01.var_table_elts[i][0] = a
                 c01.var_table_elts[i][1] = b
                 c01.var_table_elts[i][2] = c
                 c01.var_table_100[i] = 100 * i0 + 10 * i1 + i2
                 c01.var_table_sum[i] = 3 * 3 * i0 + 3 * i1 + i2
                 i+=1
   fo_table=open('table.txt','w')
   fo_table.write('#   elts    100code     sum \n')
   for i in range(0,c01.CNT_Xsize_fc,1):
      fo_table.write('\n'+ str(i)+str(c01.var_table_elts[i][0])+ str(c01.var_table_elts[i][1])+str(c01.var_table_elts[i][2]))
      sum100=c01.var_table_100[i]
      if(sum100<100):
          fo_table.write(str(sum100))
      else:
          fo_table.write(str(c01.var_table_sum[i]))
   fo_table.close()
```

gen_var_table_3()

Заполненый массив

```
CNT_Ysize=3 
CNT_Xsize=3
CNT_Xsize_fc=6
CNT= [[0 for x in range(CNT_Ysize)] for y in range(CNT_Xsize)] 
SRC= [0 for x in range(CNT_Xsize)]
KEY= [0 for x in range(CNT_Xsize)]
DST= [0 for x in range(CNT_Xsize)]
CHK= [0 for x in range(CNT_Xsize)]
var_table_elts= [[0 for x in range(CNT_Xsize_fc)] for y in range(CNT_Xsize)]
var_table_100= [0 for x in range(CNT_Xsize_fc)]
var_table_sum= [0 for x in range(CNT_Xsize_fc)]

def nexty(currenty):
    res=(currenty+1)%CNT_Ysize
    return res



  Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\c02.py", line 42, in <module>
    gen_var_table_3()
    File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\c02.py", line 26, in gen_var_table_3
    c01.var_table_elts[i][0] = a
   IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Ошибка не может возникать везде, ведь после неё код не продолжает исполняться. Пожалуйста, приведите её и полный `Traceback` в придачу. Так будет гораздо проще найти проблему.

Comment: ошибка возникает во всех операциях где используется индексация двумерного  массива

Comment: Попробуйте заменить в цикле for i на j. Или изменила индекс массива с i на что-то другое.

Comment: Ещё Михайло Ломоносов велел пользоваться отладкой. Выводите на печать значение i и все станет очевидно.

Comment: поменял , ошибка осталась

Comment: проблемы возникают только с двумерным массивом

Comment: значения i стремится от 0 до 5 размер моего массива на [6][3] элементов

Comment: Тут оф рендж все говорит. Границы диапазона установленных неверно.

Comment: просто я выводил значения i которое начиналось с 0 и заканчивалось до 5 , размер массива я увеличивал также

Comment: согласен, вы правы , на деле у меня массив [3][6]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш список `var_table_elts` имеет размерность 3 на 6, а не 6 на 3. Поэтому как только `i` принимает значение 3, вы получаете эту ошибку.

PS. Если range() начинается с 0 и имеет шаг равный единице, то оба эти параметра можно опустить и из `range(i0,c01.CNT_Xsize,1)` получается `range(c01.CNT_Xsize)`.

Comment: Спасибо только заметил